# How to get test result in MBUnit

Tags: c#, webdriver, automated-tests, mbunit, gallio

I use MBUnit and Gallio. I want to take screenshot if test resul is fail of browser before it will be closed (I use WebDriver with c#). How I can get test result in test?

Answer (score 0):

I propose the next solution:

```
Capture.AutoEmbedScreenshot( TriggerEvent.TestFailedOrInconclusive , "Last screen" , new CaptureParameters() { Zoom = 0.4 } );
```

See [bits-in-motion:blog](http://blog.bits-in-motion.com/search/label/release%20notes), there are different ways to do it.

Enjoy ;)